# Why isnt my PHP function firing from another file?

Tags: php, function, file, class, curl

I have this input element in `index.php`

```
 <input type="submit" name="OUs" value="Get all OU's">
```

This is where I fire the function in a PHP codeblock in `index.php`:

```
require_once('./OU.php');
$ou = new \Google\OU\OU();

 if(isset($_POST['OUs'])) {
    echo $ou->getOUs($response['access_token']);
 }
```

I try to run a function in `ou.php`

```
namespace Google\OU;

define("APIURL_DIRECTORY","https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/");  // For Google 
Directory actions

 class OU
{

// Get OU's
function getOUs($token){

    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/orgunits?orgUnitPath=/&type=all";
    $method = "GET";


    echo exeCurl($url,$method);
}
```

What is the reason that nothing happens when I click on that submit button? It should execute the Curl Call, shouldnt it?
I cant really figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your form tag and what does _nothing happens_ mean?

Comment: @AbraCadaver i dont have a Form tag. It is just a table with loose <input> elements 

I expect the response of the cURL call to be displayed on the screen on index.php

Comment: You have to have a form to submit.  Or some JS that is called and collects data and submits it.

Comment: I added a <form> tag and it works now thanks :)